# Full-screen problems with LibreOffice/Unity

Tags: unity, libreoffice, eeepc

I use a netbook (Asus eeePC 1005ha).  Often I work full screen in libreoffice writer.  I've noticed that when operating in a maximized window, unity locks up and sometimes freezes both programs.  Additionally, the alt+tab command doesn't display the libre office instance when it is maximized. This problem doesn't occur when the screen is in a window form.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the window maximized or fullscreen?

Comment: That alt+tab doesn't work seems to be an issue with LibreOffice itself: Even under Mac OS, keyboard shortcuts (including copy, paste etc.) do not work in LibreOffice Writer's full-screen mode.

Answer (score 3):

LibreOffice has issues going into fullscreen in Unity. The launchpad bug #768966 regarding this issue has a good work around from Daniel Centore:

"Install `compiz-plugins-extra` and `compizconfig-settings-manager`. Open ccsm and go to "Extra WM Actions." Map Toggle Fullscreen to something you will remember and use it to bring a program into fullscreen with Unity (I use <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)"